# Not put controller in application

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My application have 2 controllers, when start show a simple html with a treepanel.

Each grid has (view, model, controller and store). When i click on the treepanel node, i call the view, but if the controller of this view has declared inside the application.js this action work good, if not declare i get the error.

I create a tabpanel with the grid when i click on the treepanel node. (dynamically)

Error.
Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.importacaolist

Comment: post the code please

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('AwseomeFrontend.view.MyCustomTabPanel',{
extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias  : 'widget.mycustomtabpanel', //make sure you are using widget.something this config is not required but allow you to use Ext.widget instead of Ext.create
});
```

on app.js or application.js

make sure you have a config like this:

```
views : [
'MyCustomTabPanel' // this loads the class so you can create instances
]
```

Then you can instantiate your view from within a controller with:

```
Ext.create('AwseomeFrontend.view.MyCustomTabPanel') or Ext.widget('mycustomtabpanel')
```

*Look for typos also*

Comment: When i put the view on application.js i get the error. Even if i put a instantiate in controller. Thanks Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined Table.js?_dc=1409051472369:403

Comment: You get an error when you add your view in application.js because the framework is reading your class and founding a problem in your view. I am sure if you change your class to be a simple panel then it would work. You have to determine which config or missconfig is generating the error. regards

Answer (score 0):

Application.js

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.Application', {
name: 'ImpPdf',

extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
//create a getter of view getImportacaoListView
views: [
    'Main',
    'TabSobre',
    'TabHome',
    'TabImportacao',
    'TabTransferencia',
    'NavegacaoTree',
    'importacao.Edit',
    'importacao.List'
    /*'ClienteList',
    'AnuncioList'*/
],
//create a getter of controller getImportacaoController
controllers: [
    'Main',
    'Navegacao'
    //'Importacao'
    //'Cliente',
    //'Anuncio'
],
//create a getter of store getImportacaoStore
stores: [
    'Navegacao'
    //'Importacao'
    //'Cliente',
    //'Anuncio'
]
});
```

Main controller

```
Ext.define('ImpPdf.controller.Navegacao', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
models: ['Navegacao'],
stores: ['Navegacao'],
views: ['NavegacaoTree'],
refs: [{
    ref: 'navegacaoTree',
    selector: 'navegacaotree'
}],
init: function() {

    this.control({
        'navegacaotree': {
            itemclick: this.onNodeSelect,
            afterrender: this.onAfterRender
        }
    });
},
onNodeSelect: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    this.getController('Main').addTabPanel(record);
},
onAfterRender: function(treePanel, eOpts) {
    var store = treePanel.getStore();

    //store.setRootNode({ text:'Root', leaf:false, expended:true });

    store.load({
        scope : this,
        callback: function(records, operation, successful) {
            if (successful && records.length > 0) {

                treePanel.expandAll();

                var selectionModel = treePanel.getSelectionModel();
                selectionModel.select(0);
            }
        }
    });

}

});
```

How i create the tabpanel with a grid.

```
newTab = mainPanel.add({
            xtype: className,
            title: title
        });
```

Comment: what was the problem ?